# Create new column and assign value based on string character value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column in 4 digit numeric, I need to create another column but based on the 2nd string character value.

if the string value  is 0 , the new column data should be "M"
if the string value  is 1 , the new column data should be "A"
if the string value  is 2 or 3, the new column data would be "B"
if the string value  is 4 or 5, the new column data would be "C"
if the string value  is 6 or 7, the new column data would be "D"

I am using this code, but it is not quite right... `db[substr(code, 2, 2) %in% 0:1, c('edu') := .('A')]`

| code | edu |
| --- | --- |
| 0132 | M |
| 0045 | A |
| 2341 | B |
| 3267 | B |

Answer (score 0):

in Base R:

```
transform(df, edu = setNames(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=2),0:7)[substr(code, 2, 2)])

  code edu
1 0132   A
0 0045   A
3 2341   B
2 3267   B
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(code = c("0132", "0045", "2341", "3267")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: this works.  But what if  code 2nd string =0 then edu = "MGT".  I guess I will just add another code after?

Comment: @user15032839 you cannot have 1 value mapping to two outputs. Thats not a mathematical function. ie 0 -> A and 0-> MGT. Its  not possible, unless there is a way to distinguish the 0 from 0 haha

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear.  0 should be mapped as M.

Comment: @user15032839 In your code above, 0 is mapped to A. just change A to M.

Comment: ```dt[substr(code, 1, 1) == '0',  c('edu') := .('M')]``` is not working for some strange reason.. am I missing something?